# >why -3/2=-2 and 3/2=1 in Python

Tags: python

why is negative 3 divided by two is negative two.And three divided by two is one in Python.I have tried it on IDLE and  don't understand why.

why -3/2=-2 and 3/2=1 in Python

Comment: Possibly related:  http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Comment: Did you expect the answer to be -1.5 and 1.5 (i.e. a question about integer vs float division), or -1 and 1 (i.e. asking about floor division vs rounding towards 0)?

Comment: for -3/2,  I was expecting -1.(sorry for the delay)

Comment: @mgilson your link helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because the two numbers you are dividing are integers, python 2 floors the quotient of `3/2`.  If you want to get a float as an answer, just do `3.0/2.0` instead.  (note: you don't have to do this in python 3)

Comment: it doesnt round it rounds down ... (also known as floor)

Comment: Yep it does, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

an int divided by an int is always floored to a new int ....
(in python2x at least)

```
print math.floor(1.5),math.floor(-1.5)
```

(note that this is probably an oversimplification ....)